# Questions about Glyph sizes

Tags: pdf

I read in the [PDF Specification](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) that a glyphs's actual size depends on the `Tm`, `CTM`, and other Text state operators. Can anyone explain why?

Say that I have the values of `Tm`, `CTM`, and other text state operators (if they are applicable), how will I use them to get the glyph's size and position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CTM and TRM together define a box in which the glyf is displayed. But you would also need to consider things like the Bounding box on the Gylf and the FontBox.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but to get the `Trm`, I should multiply the `Tm` and the `CTM`, as well as the font size. Is that correct? And the resulting `Trm` is the one I'll use to get the correct text position of the characters? That's my understanding so far.

Comment: Yes. And the for every character you increment the Trm by the width plus and word and character spacing if appropriate